# Animation menu divi loading page

Tags: divi

here I have a little problem. Each time I load a page, I have the menu that makes an animation, a sort of transition from top to bottom and you can also see behind a white band. I don't really know what this is due to. Do you have an idea?
Thanks a lot
My website : https://laboxparty.com/

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are adding animations in a **column** or an **element**, and you don't have a background set as transparent in the **section** itself.

Try and set transparent background in the section if you are animating the column, or column and section both in case you are animating the menu element.

[Reference to Adding Transparent Background in a Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmIBH.png)

Comment: thanks for your answer but the main menu and the top menu had make to divi toolkit and when i use the "Before Navigation Layout" option and add top menu, an animation is activate.